# How to calculate for average by year ranges?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset with many fields. I am trying to summarize the "price" data by averages for year ranges. For example:

- 1900 to 1925: "average price"
- 1925 to 1950: "average price"
- 1950 to 1975: "average price"
- 1975 to 2000: "average price"
- 2000 to 2017: "average price"

Tried:

```
proc sql;
select avg(price) as avg_price
FROM summary
WHEN year between 1995 and 2000;
quit;
```

The code above did not work. Can you please help me with the code (please add to proc and quit or anything else I need, I am new to SAS/SQL)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRtRQ.png)

Comment: Do the prices in 1925, 1950, 1975, and 2000 contribute to one or two ranges ? In other words is the 1900 to 1925 range price average from price data in years 1900 up to but not including 1925 ?

Comment: What error did you see in the log when the code "did not work" ?

Comment: Just copy the text of the error message and paste it into the question. No need to post photographs of text.

Comment: Do you have to use SQL? A data step and PROC MEANS or PROC FORMAT + PROC MEANS is easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an year avg  then you need  group by year

```
select year, avg(price) as avg_price
FROM summary
WHERE  year between 1995 and 2000
group by year;
```

or for customn year range  a simple way  is a union

```
   select  'from 1940 to 1960', avg(price)
   from summary
   WHERE  year between 1940 and 1960
   union 
   select  'from 1960 to 1980', avg(price)
   from summary
   WHERE  year between 1960 and 1980
   union 
   select  'from 1980 to 2000', avg(price)
   from summary
   WHERE  year between 1980 and 2000
```

Comment: how can I get each year range till present in the same code? For example:
1995 to 2000: *average*
2000 to 2005: *average*
and so on

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and your expected  result as tabular data  ..

Comment: in your code, I am getting the error: ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SAS. do I have to enter proc sql in the beginning of your code or quit/run at the end?

Comment: answer  update  .. where  (not when)  and with a suggetion for custom  range

Comment: I don't think that is what I need. Please look at my question, I edited it and made it more straight forward.

Comment: what mean don't work .. you have error  .. ?? show the error message ..  wrong result  ??? add  a proper data sample  your actula result and your expected  result

Comment: sorry, don't mean to bother you. added an image above

Comment: instead  of a proc .. try test the query in a sql console or ide ..   (the error seems not related  to the sql code itselft)

Comment: I am a little confused as to what that means. What do you mean by "test the query is a sql console or ide" I am new to SAS.

Comment: i don't know how work SAS but for others DB normally the test for sql code  ..is done using a proper  tools (sql console or sql id) where is possible write directly the sql code and see the result

Answer (score 1):

I assume you really mean 1920-1924, 1925-1930, and so on, so each year is calculated once.

You can  use `group by` and arithmetic:

```
proc sql;
    select floor(year / 5) * 5 as from_year, 
           avg(price) as avg_price
    from summary
    group by floor(year / 5);   
quit;
```

If you want the end year as well:

```
proc sql;
    select floor(year / 5) * 5 as from_year, 
           floor(year / 5) * 5 + 4 as to_year, 
           avg(price) as avg_price
    from summary
    group by floor(year / 5);   
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get seem to indicate that the variable year is a string rather than numeric. The following conversion should help

```
  PROC SQL;
    SELECT mean(price) as average FROM have 
    WHERE 1995 <= input(year,8.) <= 2000 ;
  quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can `group by` a `case` statement or by a computed variable (aka column). The averaging function in SQL is `MEAN`

Example grouping by computed column:

```
data have;
  do date = '01jan1900'd to '31dec2020'd;
    year = year(date);
    yearChar = put(year,4.);
    price = exp ((date - '01jan1940'd) / (365*12) );
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select
    case 
      when year between 1900 and 1924 then '1900 to 1924'
      when year between 1925 and 1949 then '1925 to 1949'
      when year between 1950 and 1974 then '1950 to 1974'
      when year between 1975 and 1999 then '1975 to 1999'
      when year between 2000 and 2017 then '2000 to 2017'
      else 'out of range'
    end
    as years
  , mean (price) as average_price
  from have
  group by years
  having years not in ('out of range')
;
```

will create a data set such as

```
years ($12)     average_price (double)
1900 to 1924       0.120
1925 to 1949       0.967
1950 to 1974       7.777
1975 to 1999      62.546
2000 to 1917     345.873
```

For the case of the `year` variable being a character type, you will need to convert the value to a numeric and use the converted value in the `between` expression involving numbers.

Example:

`YearChar` is a character column named containing the year values.  The `input` function converts character strings into a numeric value (if possible). The question mark `?` prevents log messages when the conversion fails (such as when year is `****` or `UNKN`)

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select
    case 
      when input(yearChar,?4.) between 1900 and 1924 then '1900 to 1924'
      when input(yearChar,?4.) between 1925 and 1949 then '1925 to 1949'
      when input(yearChar,?4.) between 1950 and 1974 then '1950 to 1974'
      when input(yearChar,?4.) between 1975 and 1999 then '1975 to 1999'
      when input(yearChar,?4.) between 2000 and 2017 then '2000 to 2017'
      else 'out of range'
    end
    as years
  , mean (price) as average_price
  from have
  group by years
  having years not in ('out of range')
;
```